# Why can't Cmake find Boost components?

Tags: windows, boost, cmake

I'm trying to build an open source project called [tds2pdb](https://github.com/Josko/tds2pdb) on Windows.  It requires Boost, so I downloaded [Boost 1.78.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_78_0.html) and built libraries by the recommended method of using commands `bootstrap` and `.\b2`.  Then I fired up the Cmake GUI and told it where to find Boost. But when I click Configure, it says it is missing 3 components.

[image: cmake screen shot]

Errors as text:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem program_options iostreams) (found
  suitable version "1.78.0", minimum required is "1.55")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2375 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package)
```

The necessary libraries are definitely there in the `boost_1_78_0\stage\lib` directory, so I don't understand why they aren't being found.

---

Following a suggestion in a comment, I set the flag `Boost_DEBUG`, and then the output is as follows:

```
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1688 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.78.0;1.78;1.77.0;1.77;1.76.0;1.76;1.75.0;1.75;1.74.0;1.74;1.73.0;1.73;1.72.0;1.72;1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1689 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1690 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1691 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1692 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1693 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1725 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:\Code\boost_1_78_0"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1726 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1727 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1728 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1729 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "C:\Code\boost_1_78_0\stage"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1730 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1818 ] location of version.hpp: C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/boost/version.hpp
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1858 ] Boost_VERSION = "107800"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1859 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.78.0"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1860 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107800"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1861 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1862 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "78"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1863 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1864 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1888 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1889 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-vc143;-vc142;-vc141;-vc140" (guessed)
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1925 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2003 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (detected)
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2007 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2008 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-gd"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2068 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:\Code\boost_1_78_0\stage;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.3;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2069 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:\Code\boost_1_78_0\stage;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.3;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/../lib64-msvc-14.0;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_78/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_77/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_76/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_75/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_74/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_73/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_72/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib64-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.3;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.2;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.1;C:/boost/lib64-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2254 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64;boost_filesystem-vc143-mt;boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64;boost_filesystem-vc142-mt;boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-x64;boost_filesystem-vc141-mt;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-x64;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-mt-x64;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2309 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_filesystem-vc141-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_filesystem-mt-gd-x64;boost_filesystem-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2254 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc143-mt;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt;boost_program_options-mt-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-mt-x64;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2309 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc143-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc142-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc141-mt-gd;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x64;boost_program_options-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2254 ] Searching for IOSTREAMS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_iostreams-vc143-mt-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc143-mt-x64;boost_iostreams-vc143-mt;boost_iostreams-vc142-mt-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc142-mt-x64;boost_iostreams-vc142-mt;boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-x64;boost_iostreams-vc141-mt;boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-x64;boost_iostreams-vc140-mt;boost_iostreams-mt-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-mt-x64;boost_iostreams-mt;boost_iostreams-mt;boost_iostreams
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2309 ] Searching for IOSTREAMS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_iostreams-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_iostreams-vc143-mt-gd;boost_iostreams-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_iostreams-vc142-mt-gd;boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_iostreams-vc141-mt-gd;boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_iostreams-vc140-mt-gd;boost_iostreams-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_iostreams-mt-gd-x64;boost_iostreams-mt-gd;boost_iostreams-mt;boost_iostreams
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2254 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_regex-vc143-mt-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc143-mt-x64;boost_regex-vc143-mt;boost_regex-vc142-mt-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc142-mt-x64;boost_regex-vc142-mt;boost_regex-vc141-mt-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc141-mt-x64;boost_regex-vc141-mt;boost_regex-vc140-mt-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc140-mt-x64;boost_regex-vc140-mt;boost_regex-mt-x64-1_78;boost_regex-mt-x64;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex
[ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2309 ] Searching for REGEX_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_regex-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc143-mt-gd-x64;boost_regex-vc143-mt-gd;boost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc142-mt-gd-x64;boost_regex-vc142-mt-gd;boost_regex-vc141-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc141-mt-gd-x64;boost_regex-vc141-mt-gd;boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-x64;boost_regex-vc140-mt-gd;boost_regex-mt-gd-x64-1_78;boost_regex-mt-gd-x64;boost_regex-mt-gd;boost_regex-mt;boost_regex
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: filesystem program_options iostreams) (found
  suitable version "1.78.0", minimum required is "1.55")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2375 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package)
```

I note in particular that in `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE`, one of the paths is `C:\Code\boost_1_78_0/stage/lib`, and that's where the libraries are.  Also, in `Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE`, the first name given is `boost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_78`, and the directory does contain a file named `libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib`.

Comment: As indicated by the error message, however you built Boost did not include the `filesystem`, `program_options`, or `iostreams` components. Also, you should probably paste the error message as plain text rather than as a picture...

Comment: @AlexReinking  I do see, for instance, libboost_iostreams-vc143-mt-gd-x32-1_78.lib, libboost_iostreams-vc143-mt-gd-x64-1_78.lib, libboost_iostreams-vc143-mt-x32-1_78.lib, libboost_iostreams-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib in the stage\lib folder, so it certainly seems like I built the iostreams component.

Comment: Pass additional `Boost_DEBUG` parameter (set to TRUE) to CMake. That way CMake will print exact file names which is searched for Boost libraries. Compare these names with ones you actually have.

Comment: @Tsyvarev OK, I have done that, and added the information to the question, but I still don't understand the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got past the Boost errors by setting a cmake flag `Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS`.  Now I'm getting errors about GTest, but I guess that would be a different question.